# Django Error: ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Tags: python, django, python-venv

I'm having some problems when running django on my machine, even though it's inside the virtual machine it accuses an error, I'm using macOS. Below is an image of my manage.py

[Print screen Manage.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvDRr.png)

Comment: Is Django installed in the virtual environment? 
Did you run `python -m pip install Django`?

Comment: yes, but it does not recognize the installation

Comment: I used this and it solved my problem, it wasn't installing on venv, on another computer it worked, it must be some configuration, I don't know, thanks for the help!